# How can I redirect User to "parks/:campgroundId" page from the login post route,Using Nodejs and Passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js

**Hi**

I have problem redirecting to a page with **ID** from my **login post route**, here is my code:

```
//Sign In Routes
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    req.flash("error", "Please login first!");
    res.render("login");
});
//handling login logic
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect: "/login"}), function(req, res) {
    Campground.find({}, function(err, allCampgrounds){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{ 
            allCampgrounds.forEach(function(theCampground){
                if(theCampground.members === req.user._id){
                    res.redirect("/parks/" + theCampground.id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

this code redirects me back to "/login" page when i'm sure user is registered by that username and password.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Not much to go on here, but presuming `/parks/:campgroundId` is a secure route, then it looks like you aren't properly persisting the authentication information after the user successfully logs in.

Comment: Thank you @James , _/parks/:campgroundId_ is secure, is everything after _function(req, res) {_ happen in case of _successful.redirect_ ?

Comment: yes but it's up to you to implement the "secure" part i.e. Passport is just a framework that provides you hooks, I presume you've implement the security part correctly? Also, as per the answer by serifcetiner it would be help if you explained how you trigger the login, if this is indeed from AJAX then he is correct, server-side redirect won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this call Ajax or Form ? You cannot redirect Ajax request on serverside, you need to return some response to your client side code and redirect it 
 at client such as

windows.location = '/parks/123'